# Showing a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given that $V$ is over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{u, v, w\}$ are distinct and a basis of $V$. Show that $$\{u - (1 +i)v, u+v+w, -2iu\}$$ is also a basis.

So far, I have just started by stating that they must be linear combinations of $V$. Such that:

$$u = a_1 (u-(1+i)v),\ v = a_2 (u+v+w),\ w = a_3 (-2iu).$$

But I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Show that they can't be expressed as linear combination of each other? Show that they span the space?

Comment: Sorry what is your question? yes I want to determine if they are linear combos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a direction to help get you going:

To be a basis, those three new vectors --- let's call them $u', v', w'$ --- have to be linearly independent, and have to span $V$.

Suppose that 
$$
a_1 u' + a_2 v' + a_3 w' = 0.
$$
By replacing $u'$ with $u + (1+i)v$, and similarly for the other two, you get an equation involving $u,v, w$.

- What are the coefficients in that equation?
- What can you say about the coefficients, knowing that $u,v, w$ are linearly independent?
- What does that tell you about $a_1, a_2, a_3$?

If all that works out, you'll have shown linear independence. What do you have to do to show that the three new vectors also *span* $V$? [If you know theorems about dimension, this is a lot easier. If not, you've got some actual work to do.]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the format of an answer I was looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, do I set each part equal to 0 then solve for a? (ie. a_2(u+v+w) = 0)

Comment: See the second bullet above: knowing that $u, v, w$ are independent and that $pu + qv + rw = 0$ (where $p, q, r$ are real), what can you say about $p, q, $ and $r$? (If you can't answer...then please go re-read the definition of linearly independent.)

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly faster way, to show it would be to use a transformation matrix for a change of basis but you need to know a bit of theory behind.

Imagine the new vectors as images of the old vectors in a linear map. Write the matrix of this map (in the old basis) - you get a 3x3 matrix. Show that the matrix has full rank (which is equivalent to invertibility for square matrices). As a consequence you get that the new vectors form a basis as well.